# Is there any way to get past the glitch in Crash Site when in the plane

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops

My other half is stuck in "Crash Site" in Black Ops. Having made it up to the plane she can't get the China Lake to appear and continue on. Having roamed all the way around the plane nothing triggers.

Is the only option to restart the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting from checkpoint, if that won't help start mission again.
If that won't work either, I think you know what you will have to do.

Comment: Yep in the end we had to restart the level. Luckily it's not too long to the plane.